# Compound types, const and auto in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

I'm trying to understand this piece of code. I'm stuck at figuring out why `d` and `e` are `int*` and `const int*`. I could use some help.

```
const int ci = i, &cr = ci;
auto b = ci; // b is an int (top-level const in ci is dropped)
auto c = cr; // c is an int (cr is an alias for ci whose const is top-level)
auto d = &i; // d is an int*(& of an int object is int*)
auto e = &ci; // e is const int*(& of a const object is low-level const)
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. The definition of `i` is missing in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&i` means *"take the address of `i`"*. Since `i` is a `int`, the type of `&i` is `int*`. The type of `d` is deduced as `int*` due to [automatic type deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

The same reasoning can be applied to `ci`. The only difference is the `const` qualifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @BiancaStan if this answer suits you, please click the checkmark around the answer's score. That's better than saying thank you ;)